# How to capture ajax drop down list value in MVC 3 view?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have the following view that has tow dropdowns and one button:

```
@model RoomReservation.Webb.Models.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Select a city and a hotel</legend>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.City_DDL_ID, new SelectList(Model.AllCities, "Value", "Text"),"...pick a city..." )
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Hotel_DDL_ID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "...pick a hotel...", new { disabled = "disabled"})
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="SearchButton" type="submit"  onclick="window.location.href='/Home/SearchForRooms'" disabled="disabled"/> 
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#City_DDL_ID').change(function () {
        var selectedCity = $(this).val();
        if (selectedCity != null && selectedCity != '-1') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetHotels")', { id: selectedCity }, function (hotels) {
                var hotelsSelect = $('#Hotel_DDL_ID');
                hotelsSelect.empty();
                $.each(hotels, function (index, hotel) {
                    hotelsSelect.append($('<option/>',
                    {
                        value: hotel.Value,
                        text: hotel.Text
                    }));
                });
                $('#Hotel_DDL_ID').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#SearchButton').attr('disabled', false);

            });
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function onsubmitclcik() {
    var SecondDrpId = $('#Hotel_DDL_ID').val();
    window.location.href = '/Home/SearchForRooms?parameter=' + SecondDrpId;
```

}

I would like to get a value from second dropdown so that I can give it as paramater to my method f**ired from the button atribute "onclick". It is now working (above script).
But my action still gets null parameter. Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult SearchForRooms(int SecondDrpId) 
    {
        if (SecondDrpId > -1)
            return View(); //Here goes some model, not important
        else
            return RedirectToRoute("Home/Index");
    }
```

Here is the Chrome parameter:
Request URL:http://localhost:22191/Home/SearchForRooms?parameter=3
Request Method:GET 
thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to solve your problem.

```
<input id="SearchButton" type="submit" onclick="onsubmitclcik();"  disabled="disabled"/>
```

Write a javascript function to call your next url,

```
function onsubmitclcik() {
        var SecondDrpId = $('#Hotel_DDL_ID').val();
        window.location.href = '/Home/SearchForRooms?parameter=' + SecondDrpId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still GET null referense for parameter, here is my function: public ActionResult SearchForRooms(string hotelValue) 
        {
            var @int = Int32.Parse(hotelValue);
            if (@int > -1)
                return View();
            else
                return RedirectToRoute("Home/Index");
        }

Comment: You have to make the name of the parameter identical to the name of the action parameter: `window.location.href = '/Home/SearchForRooms?SecondDrpId=' + SecondDrpId;`

Comment: Your javascript function should be,

function onsubmitclcik() {
        var SecondDrpId = $('#Hotel_DDL_ID').val();
        window.location.href = '/Home/SearchForRooms?hotelValue=' + SecondDrpId ;
}

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling your action by setting `window.location.href` to your actions url?
That way, not a single parameter will be sent to your action.
Either add the parameter to the url and name it like your action paramter is named. In your example the parameter has to be called `SecondDrpId`:

```
onclick="window.location.href='/Home/SearchForRooms?SecondDrpId=' + $('#Hotel_DDL_ID').val()"
```

Or embed your dropdowns inside a form and post it to your action method.